# Requests from a specific older version of Firefox distributed across many Google and Cloudflare IP addresses

Tags: user-agent, access-control, logs, request

I've been getting thousands of requests each day from a specific user agent, `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0`. They're all from different IP addresses (the ones I've looked up have been Google LLC and Cloudflare), and they all use that exact same user agent.
[image: nginx logs]
So far I've seen 90 unique IP addresses

[image: ip count]

I've started giving `403` statuses back to them, since it seems like something is wrong here, but I can't trace them back to any one specific point. They all seem to be legitimate requests, but they're just so suspicious with the amount of servers they're coming from. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why do you think they are legitimate? For a start there is no referer and thise URLs look like md5 sums.  Has the site been compromised? What was being returned prior to your 403? Why are you returning a 403 rather then a 404?  Its not uncommon for attacks to use a pool of compromised IPs. Have you considered fail2ban to reduce the impact?

Comment: I thought they were legitimate because this is a json/image api, so many requests are expected as it's decently popular. Those are md5 sums, md5 sums of images hosted for said image api. I now know this is how Discord fetches images for embeds, as it fails to load images while I block these requests, so they are legitimate, Discord is just dumb and uses a browser user agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to find that this is [Discord](https://discord.com) doing this, as it uses this user agent for fetching images for embeds (maybe the default electron user agent or something similar?), and I can tell as I started blocking requests using that user agent, images in Discord embeds that pointed to my servers started to fail to load.